# Project crashing

Tags: critical-path

Just had a question regarding Project crashing. I wanted to know when is the exact time we need to stop reducing the project schedule?

Do we need to carry on until all critical paths are 0 because it even says we can reduce the schedule until we reach the crash point of the network. Sorry if my understanding is little, getting stuck at where to stop as at University we did not  have to plot the graph and there were no indirect costs given.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a great article on project crashing in PMI that addresses your concerns.

> ...
>
> In practice the most common requirement for project re-planning
>   calculations concern time and cost. Clients often ask for projects to
>   be speeded up and need to know how much of an increase in speed is
>   possible as well as what it will cost.
>
> The analysis and execution of this time change, and its attendant
>   impact on cost, is commonly known as crash analysis. In crash
>   analysis, a project manager offers re-planning advice based on the
>   functional relationship between time and cost. The objective is to
>   look at that relationship for the process concerned and to generate an
>   alternative cost and time scenarios. The client can see how much it
>   will cost to meet a range of different time options.
>
> ...
>
> Knowing the critical path in the project schedule is key. This will
>   dictate the current finish date for the project. It will also identify
>   the activities that need to be reduced if the project is to be
>   completed sooner that what was first envisaged. By assessing the
>   associated costs of reducing the critical activities, it is possible
>   to select the most cost effective crash sequence.

From: Kelly, Éamonn V. (2009). "Crash with confidence". Available online at: https://www.pmi.org/learning/library/performing-crash-analysis-alternative-cost-schedule-6750